# I am using Whisper to transcribe and I am getting the below error, unable to figure out the issue

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, speech-to-text, valueerror, openai-whisper

I am using Whisper to transcribe an audio file. I have installed Python3.9, ffmpeg and the associated dependencies, and openai-whisper==20230308. I could import whisper, but when I try to run transcribe:

```py
audio = f'audio_dataset/testaudio.wav'
model = whisper.load_model("base") 

result = model.transcribe(audio, fp16=False,language="en")
```

...I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [32], line 1
----> 1 result = model.transcribe(audio, fp16=False, language="en")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py:27, in _DecoratorContextManager.__call__.<locals>.decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     24 @functools.wraps(func)
     25 def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26     with self.clone():
---> 27         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whisper/decoding.py:811, in decode(model, mel, options, **kwargs)
    808 if kwargs:
    809     options = replace(options, **kwargs)
--> 811 result = DecodingTask(model, options).run(mel)
    813 return result[0] if single else result

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/whisper/decoding.py:522, in DecodingTask.__init__(self, model, options)
    520 self.initial_tokens: Tuple[int] = self._get_initial_tokens()
    521 self.sample_begin: int = len(self.initial_tokens)
--> 522 self.sot_index: int = self.initial_tokens.index(tokenizer.sot)
    524 # inference: implements the forward pass through the decoder, including kv caching
    525 self.inference = PyTorchInference(model, len(self.initial_tokens))

ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Comment: What debugging efforts have you tried?

Comment: I initially tried running loading whisper model and running transcribe. Had issues. Then I installed Whisper in a virtual environment along with ffmpeg. Facing the same issues. Uninstalled and reinstalled openai-whisper=20230308 along with ffmpeg installed from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos#IfYouNeedHelp and I still see the same error.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I installed using using pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git  and I did not have whisper-openai installed previously. Something else is conflicting for some strange reason.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue.
I was using **whisper-openai** package.

This worked for me: 
`pip uninstall openai-whisper`  
`pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Let me do this and check it out. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks Anton Leshkevich, I did uninstall and reinstall the latest version of openai-whisper and it works now.